# How to create a reactive Donut Chart in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I want to create a Donut Chart in Shiny that pulls values from each row every second or two and make changes to slice length

Dataframe:

```
df <- tibble(
  Date_Time = as.POSIXct(c(
    "2023-06-14 09:43:09", "2023-06-14 09:43:12", "2023-06-14 09:43:16",
    "2023-06-14 09:43:19", "2023-06-14 09:43:22", "2023-06-14 09:43:09",
    "2023-06-14 09:43:12", "2023-06-14 09:43:16", "2023-06-14 09:43:19",
    "2023-06-14 09:43:22", "2023-06-14 09:43:09", "2023-06-14 09:43:12",
    "2023-06-14 09:43:16", "2023-06-14 09:43:19", "2023-06-14 09:43:22",
    "2023-06-14 09:43:09", "2023-06-14 09:43:12", "2023-06-14 09:43:16",
    "2023-06-14 09:43:19", "2023-06-14 09:43:22"
  )),
  car_name = c(
    "car1", "car1", "car1", "car1", "car1", "car2", "car2", "car2", "car2", "car2",
    "car3", "car3", "car3", "car3", "car3", "car4", "car4", "car4", "car4", "car4"
  ),
  car_Price  = c(
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 219857, 319857, 219857, 619857, 109857,
    187081, 197081, 187081, 117081, 107081, 3416, 3426, 5996, 3426, 926
  )
)
```

Shiny App without the reactivty:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Car Price"),
  mainPanel(
    plotlyOutput("donutChart")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$donutChart <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(
      data = df,
      labels = ~car_name,
      values = ~car_Price ,
      type = "pie",
      hole = 0.5,
      text = ~paste(car_Price),
      textinfo = "text",
      hoverinfo = "label"
    )
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Desired Output Example:

[image]

How to change the code to make similar output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for this.

```
df <- tibble(
  Date_Time = as.POSIXct(c(
    "2023-06-14 09:43:09", "2023-06-14 09:43:12", "2023-06-14 09:43:16",
    "2023-06-14 09:43:19", "2023-06-14 09:43:22", "2023-06-14 09:43:09",
    "2023-06-14 09:43:12", "2023-06-14 09:43:16", "2023-06-14 09:43:19",
    "2023-06-14 09:43:22", "2023-06-14 09:43:09", "2023-06-14 09:43:12",
    "2023-06-14 09:43:16", "2023-06-14 09:43:19", "2023-06-14 09:43:22",
    "2023-06-14 09:43:09", "2023-06-14 09:43:12", "2023-06-14 09:43:16",
    "2023-06-14 09:43:19", "2023-06-14 09:43:22"
  )),
  car_name = c(
    "car1", "car1", "car1", "car1", "car1", "car2", "car2", "car2", "car2", "car2",
    "car3", "car3", "car3", "car3", "car3", "car4", "car4", "car4", "car4", "car4"
  ),
  car_Price  = c(
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 219857, 319857, 219857, 619857, 109857,
    187081, 197081, 177081, 117081, 107081, 3416, 3426, 5996, 3446, 926
  )
)

df1 <- df %>% 
  group_by(car_name) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(rowid = row_number())

library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Car Price"),
  useShinyjs(),
  mainPanel(
    shinyjs::hidden(sliderInput("row","Choose row number",
                min(unique(df1$rowid)), max(unique(df1$rowid)), value=1, step=1, 
                animate = animationOptions(
                  interval = 1000,
                  loop = TRUE,
                  playButton = NULL,
                  pauseButton = NULL
                )
                )),
    tags$script("$(document).ready(function(){
                        setTimeout(function() {$('.slider-animate-button').click()},10);
                    });"),
    plotlyOutput("donutChart")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  dfa <- reactive({
    df1[df1$rowid == input$row, ]
  })
  
  output$donutChart <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(
      data = dfa(),
      labels = ~car_name,
      values = ~car_Price ,
      type = "pie",
      hole = 0.5,
      text = ~paste(car_Price),
      textinfo = "text",
      hoverinfo = "label"
    )
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Is there any way to use this without  the use of slider input? Thanks!

Comment: Sure.  Hide the slider.